# Java equivalent of C++ output stream overloading

Tags: java

I'm moving into Java from a C++ background and I'm currently getting to grips with the notion of not overloading operators, as is the Java way. I'm currently trying to figure out how to handle a situation where, if I were writing in C++, I would overload `operator<<` for my class and call it a day.

How should this situation be handled in Java? Is there a specific procedure with specific syntax, or it is as simple as writing something like

```
public void PrintMyStuff( final MyClass myClass ){
    System.out.print( /*MyClass member1*/ );
    System.out.print( /*MyClass member2*/ );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you've answered your own question. To put a little more "ritual" and "the right way to do things" into things - the convention is for this "printing method" to be called toString(), and it should return a String - that String is then printed explicitly.

(...though I won't tattle on you if you just print in the method like you want to... especially if it's only for your own purposes...)

Here is the salient link about this convention: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=55

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to get a string representation of an object? If so, just override the `toString()` method. For example:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(member1);
    ...
    sb.append(member2);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

A `StringBuilder` would be the closest equivalent to a `std::stringstream` i guess.

*hth*